# How to Change AutoCollapse Value true/false in Nebular menu in different Components?

Tags: angular, nebular

HTML code :

```
<nb-menu *ngIf="enableCollapse == true" autoCollapse [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
<nb-menu *ngIf="disableCollapse == true"  [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Component.ts

```
export class MainComponent { 
    enableCollapse: boolean = true;
    disableCollapse: boolean = false; 
    menu = MENU_ITEMS;
}
```

In some components, while routing I have to keep AutoCollapse Disabled and in some, it is enabled, 
So How can I Pass
True/false values over here from other components so that in some pages the sidebar menu auto-collapse is enabled in some pages it is disabled.
Any help is Appreciated

Comment: Do you have just one `ng-menu` in  your application ? `NbMenuService` that may help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass the `true`/`false` value to the `autoCollapse` property like this:

```
<nb-menu autoCollapse="false" [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
```

or

```
<nb-menu [autoCollapse]="enableCollapse" [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
```

As a side note, there is no need in two variables to control the `autoCollapse` feature, just one flag would be enough.